# PHP post - converting time in form

Tags: php, html

i want to build a site, where a user can choose a timeslot. This timeslot should be printed on the following site. But i have a problem with the correct presentation or displaying the chosen time.

Here my code so far:

Site1, where the user choose a timeslot:

```
                    <form name="Uhrzeit" action="confirmation.php" method="POST">
                <?php
                $start = 10;
                $end = 18;

                for ($time = $start; $time <= $end; $time++) {
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='Zeit'>";
                    echo date("H:00", mktime($time+0,25)).'<br>';
                  }
                ?>
                <input type="submit" value="Wählen">
                </form>
```

Site2, where the chosen time should be printed:

```
<?php
$new_date = date('H:00', strtotime($_POST['Zeit']));
echo $new_date;
?>
```

But with this i get everytime the output of "01:00".

Comment: You need to add the time as a `value` on the checkboxes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: and how can i implement this as a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

```
<form name="Uhrzeit" action="confirmation.php" method="POST">
<?php
$start = 10;
$end = 18;

for ($time = $start; $time <= $end; $time++) {
echo "<input type='radio' name='Zeit' value='".date("H:00", mktime($time+0,25))."'>";
echo date("H:00", mktime($time+0,25)).'<br>';
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Wählen">
</form>
```

Comment: It's always preferred that you include an explanation of what the issue is and what the code you post solves and how, instead of just "try this".

Comment: In your radio button, value attribute was not set. I have set it.